# mysql table move insertions

Tags: mysql, select, insert, transfer

This might be hard to understand so let me know if I need to describe it better. Say I have 3 tables tableA, tableB, and tableC with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    data_point_1 VARCHAR(30),
    data_point_2 VARCHAR(30),
    data_point_3 VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE tableB (
    bid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data_point_1 VARCHAR(30),
);

CREATE TABLE tableC (
    cid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data_point_2 VARCHAR(30),
    data_point_3 VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Now what I want to do is transfer the data from tableA into tableB and tableC. So in essence I want something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableB
SELECT
    data_point_1,
    (SELECT cid FROM tableC WHERE (INSERT INTO tableC SELECT data_point_2, data_point_3 FROM tableA))
FROM tableA
```

I haven't tried the above, but I'm assuming it is not possible since INSERT doesn't return the actual values (I would need a select I assume), but my question becomes how can I insert data from A put it into C and then at the same time grab the id from C and another data point from A and place those both into B.

I figure I can probably break it up into 2 insert statements and then do a select on C where data_point_2 = data_point_2 and data_point_3=data_point_3, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in just one query? I couldn't find anything so I figured I'd ask here.

Again: I don't want 2 separate insert queries. I want to be able to do it in 1. (Cause theoretically I might need to abstract it further)

Comment: Does no one have a response? Still haven't seen a viable way of doing this...

Comment: You might be asking for the impossible (for MySQL anyway). I'm not sure what you're concerns are, but you might look into how transactions work. They are a way you can make many statements practically 'happen all at once'.

Comment: From the looks of it it might be impossible then since no one can find a solution. Thanks =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution looks to be that there is no solution =/  guess i'll have to do it in multiple inserts. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do itin two statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TableB(data_point_1) SELECT data_point_1 FROM TableA
INSERT INTO TablEc(data_point_2,data_point_3) SELECT data_point_2, data_point_3 FROM TableA
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it fails to point tableB to tableC. We need to make sure that tableB.cid maps to the proper row in tableC. And as I have already mentioned that I already know how to do it in 2 inserts... I was wondering if it was possible in just one query statement.